# Android listview setOnItemClickListener and textview setOnLongClickListener together?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Rewrote the entire question. Here's a reduced example of what I am trying to do. I have a listview with a custom adapter. Each row generated by the adapter has multiple textviews. On two of the textviews, a longclick will generate a dialog. Whereas in the other view, nothing is done. On all 3 views, if I click on them. The listview's onitemclick should be fired. I hope this reduced example will help someone understand better what I am trying to achieve and a solution could be proposed.

The problem with the code (If you try it yourself), is that onitemclick is not fired for the two textviews which has an onlongclicklistener implemented. Anyone has any clue how to get onitemclick to fire for those two textviews? Thanks.

I have a listview with a custom arrayadapter:

```
public class TestListView  extends ListView{
    final Context mContext;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public TestListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;

        list.add("Blue");
        list.add("Green");
        list.add("Red");
        list.add("Black");

        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(context, 0, list);
        this.setAdapter(adapter);

        this.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Log.i("ApplicationName", "onItemClick " + position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        Context context;
        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_view_row, parent, false);
      TextView tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
      TextView tv2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
      TextView tv3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

      tv1.setText(this.getItem(position));
      tv2.setText("tv2 text");
      tv3.setText("tv3 text");

      tv1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage("You have onLongClicked a textview with color")
                .setPositiveButton(
                        "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        tv3.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage("You have onLongClicked a generic textview")
                .setPositiveButton(
                        "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
      return rowView;
    }

  }
}
```

With the inflatable xmlView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You dont require long click listener for dialog

Comment: I know I don't. But that's the functionality I would like to have in the listview. When the user longclicks on the textview, a dialog pops up. If the user onclicks the textview, onitemclick should be fired just like any other view in the row.

Comment: Post your code how you are setting your list adapter

Comment: what are the other views in row?

Comment: Basically other textviews. But I only want the longclick listener for that particular textview.

Comment: have you checked my edit?

Comment: Yeah, just did. Still can't get it working. I found a blog post saying that once you set a view's clicklistener (any one) in a listview, it gets removed from the itemlisteners for the listview. But I can't find the blogpost anymore.

What I tried from your suggestion:

this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
this.setFocusable(true);
this.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);

And the onlongclicklistener for the textview has always been in the adapter of the listview.

Comment: Elltz, I came up with a reduced version of the problem. Please reread, I hope you understand the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>first of all make your listview clickable by `Listview.Setclickable(true);`</strike> -(was refering to the textview sorry) and do the same for the textview.. and also add focusable && focusbaleInTouchMode for the textview to true
also for the listview do this..  `Listview. setDescendantFocusability (View.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);`

and put your textview <strike>onlongitemclicklistener</strike> **onlongclicklistener** in your adapter rather..
note im just typing, im not rechecking for silly errors so do that..im late already..thanks
let me know if it helps

thanks for the correction

**copy and paste this**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

List<Object> AndroidPlist; 
int AndroidPres;
Context AndroidPcontext;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Object> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.AndroidPcontext = context;
    this.AndroidPlist = objects;
    this.AndroidPres = resource;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(AndroidPlist == null){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return AndroidPlist.size();
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return AndroidPlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View child = convertView;
    final RecordHolder holder;
    if (child == null) { // checking for null
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) AndroidPcontext).getLayoutInflater(); // inflating the view
        child = inflater.inflate(AndroidPres, parent, false);
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tv);   // referencing your textview        
        child.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) child.getTag(); //
    }
    holder.name.setText("set your text") // 
    holder.name.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // Hurray AndroidP, Elltz has solved your problem.. lol.


            return false;
        }
    });

    return child;
}

static class RecordHolder {
    TextView name;
}
}
```

setonclick for your listview and should work now..if it doesn't-(which i doubt).. just put the same method you put in the listview onclick in the textview onlclick..lol.. you aint got a problem? do you?

Comment: Tried it all, same problem:

tv.setClickable(true);
tv.setFocusable(true);
tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

and in listview Oncreate:

this.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);

btw, textview does not have an onlongitemclicklistener, I think you meant onlongclicklistener? That's in the adapter already.

Comment: this is what im guessing it calls it, but..try this put a `Log.v("Onclic""recevd");` in your textview onlongclick.. and see if its called..@AndroidP

Comment: longclicking on the textview isn't a problem. Clicking on the textview does not trigger the onitemclick for listview though. That is where I am having difficulties with.

Comment: did you use `View.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS` ?? if so remove it.. i tot your problem was the textview now you say listview? well its cool just remove that..@AndroidP

Comment: Well, it's both actually. I want to longclick the textview for a dialog to pop up, and a onitemclick the listview to go to another activity. Onitemclick should also trigger when I click on the textview but that isn't triggering if I put a onlongclicklistener on the textview.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you

```
            tv1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() { 

                    @Override 
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                      // Put a Toast here and try 
                      //  Test long click works 
                    } 
                });
```

Comment: I'm confused. What I I missing here. I don't want the onclick for the textview. The textview should only have the onlongclick listener. If the textview is indeed clicked, then I'd like to activate the listview onitemclick just like if the other textviews in the row was clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle setOnClicklistener while you define following line in your xmlView:

```
 android:singleLine="true"
```

Change it with:

```
android:lines="1"
```

It's strange but it's working